# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'quote'. 'OrderBy' not found

Tags: sql, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I've not worked with LINQ for some time so my knowledge is shaky.  The following C# expression runs in LinqPad against the database.

```
(from q in Quotes
orderby q.Quotedate
where (q.Underlying == "aapl")
select new {q.Quotedate, q.Underlying})
.Distinct().OrderBy(q => q.Quotedate)
```

Now, I'm trying to incorporate this into my project using EF6 like this:

```
 using (var dbcontext = new MarketDataAnalysisDBEntities())
 {
       var query = (from q in quote
                         orderby q.Quotedate
                         where (q.Underlying == "aapl")
                         select new { q.Quotedate, q.Underlying })
                         .Distinct().OrderBy(q => q.Quotedate)
 };
```

But I get the error "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'quote'.  'OrderBy' not found." If I remove the OrderBy it gives the same error about "where" not found.

I am referencing system.data, system.linq, system.data.entity in the class.  This is VS2017 RC1 and EF6 inside a class library project (part of larger webapi solution).

The order is less critical, but, getting Distinct(dates) is critical as the result set drops to ~1k versus >1m

What am I missing?

Comment: Your linq pad version uses `Quotes` and not `quote`, Is that intended? If so, what is the definition of `quote`?

Comment: I would also expect use of your db context, ie `from q in dbcontext.Quotes` (or similarly accessing some property of the context) as it stands you aren't using your context for anything

Comment: The table name in LinqPad uses the capital "Q" while EF generated an entity using "q".  quotes is a table name and is defined as part of the DB context....when I referenced the context directly I realized this is a giant cut-n-paste issue as the capitalization of nearly everything is different in the EF context.  I think my issue is resolved.  Sorry about that.